# Дополнить TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

Не получается дописать в `TextView`. Выдает

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Может у кого есть идеи т.к. про бывал вот это `logGameTextView.text = logGameTextView.text as String + (getString(R.string.restart)` и получал

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var logTextView:TextView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)
    logGameTextView = findViewById(R.id.text_view_log)
    logGameTextView.text = "..."
    logGameTextView.text = logTextView.text + getString(R.string.restart)
  }
}
```

Comment: А если так: `logGameTextView.text = logTextView.text.toString() + getString(R.string.restart)`?

Comment: Либо так: `logGameTextView.append(getString(R.string.restart))`

Comment: Это работает, но ide предлагает вот эти два варианта 

`private operator fun CharSequence.plus(string: String): CharSequence? {}`

`private operator fun Any.plus(string: String): CharSequence? {}`

Но лучше на вашем варианте всё таки остановлюсь на `logGameTextView.append(getString(R.string.restart))`